# WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback doesn't work anymore

Tags: flutter, dart

I used to use

```
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
```

for doing something after widget is built.

However after updating flutter this error occurs

```
Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('../../../fvm/versions/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
```

Is there any workaround??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a `!` after `instance` like so `WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback`

Comment: Thank you very much I need to understand `!` more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    // do your stuff
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are use the getx package,update the getx package version in the pupspect.yaml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).